# Fetching 1 record based on the name of the logged in User and show these values in txt boxes (c#)

Tags: c#, linq

I Want to fetch 1 record based on the name of the logged in User and show these values in txt boxes (c#)
I am a bit stuck on how to handle this, any help would be welcome.

Currently I am trying to fetch it using LINQ:

```
DAL.VindjekindjeDataContext dc = new DAL.VindjekindjeDataContext();

public object GetCompleteOuder(string p)
{
    //var query = (from TOUD in dc.TOUDs where TOUD.Ouderid == p select TOUD).Single();

    return (from TOUD in dc.TOUDs where TOUD.Voornaam.Equals(p) select TOUD ).First();

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string naam = User.Identity.Name;

    object parent = new object();
    parent = Ouder.GetCompleteOuder(naam);


    Type typB = parent.GetType();
    NaamTxt.Text = (string)typB.GetField("Naam").GetValue(parent);

}
```

However I get the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Reflection is not appropriate here, return the real type from the order getter and access it normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just too much going wrong here.

1. Your exception is possibly caused by a parent (ouder in Dutch) which has a `null` value for `Voornaam`)
2. You instantiate an object `parent` which is useless since you overwrite it the next line.
3. Your `parent` variable should be strongly typed. That will prevent you to need reflection to get the `Naam` property. This, by the way, is another possible source for your `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Maybe I had to declare this "object parent = new object();" outside the Page_Load section.

Oh I see what you mean now, I can't return a complete "parent" or row of that parent table because I have different values like "int", "string" etc. 

So if I want all the values for example the telephone nr, name, firstname etc.. 

I need to get them out 1 by 1?

Comment: @Jochem: I would just return the entire object. I don't know which type `TOUD` is, but I guess instead of `object` you should give the type of `TOUD`.

Comment: It is the name of the Table actually that is used to store the parents in my LINQ datacontext

Comment: @Jochem: Then the type is probably the same. Try the code from Andy below.

Comment: I am still at work for the moment, but after 18:00 I'll run home and try it out! thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Jochem: Why did you remove the accepted answer? Wasn't my answer helpful?

Comment: Oh yes it was I thought they where both helpful the one of andy as well I did not know however you could only pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
public bool GetCompleteOuder(out TOUD user, string p)
{
    user = new TOUD();

    try
    {
        db.TOUDS.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Voornaam == p);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string naam = User.Identity.Name;
    TOUD user;
    if(GetCompleteOuder(out user, naam))
    {
        NaamTxt.Text = user.<fieldname>;
    }
    else
    {
        NaamTxt.Text = string.empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, this way "NaamTxt.Text = user.<fieldname>;" I can every value of user right? so I can get name, firstname, telephone nr etc...

Comment: Apparently I can't call the the type "TOUD" the compiler does not recognize it. He keeps complaining: "The type or namespace name 'TOUD' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Comment: the compiler does not complain anymore when I call it like "DAL.TOUD"

But there are no values in the "user". In you're code is the object TOUD actually being filled?

Comment: I found a solution, I will post it tonight! Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
DAL.VindjekindjeDataContext dc = new DAL.VindjekindjeDataContext();



public bool GetCompleteOuder(out DAL.TOUD  user, string p)
{
    user = new DAL.TOUD();

    try
    {
        dc.TOUDs.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Voornaam == p);
        user = (from TOUD in dc.TOUDs where TOUD.Voornaam.Equals(p) select TOUD).Single();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//page load behind aspx page

```
OuderDAL Ouder = new OuderDAL();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string naam = User.Identity.Name;

    DAL.TOUD user; 

if(Ouder.GetCompleteOuder(out user, naam))
{

    /*vullen van de velden met de gegevens voor de ingelogde gebruiker*/
    NaamTxt.Text = user.Naam;
```